# smtplib - Authentication credentials invalid - with definitely right credentials - why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, security, smtplib

Here is a minimal code which sends a test email

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import smtplib, ssl
from email.message import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage()
msg.set_content("Email body")
msg["Subject"] = "Email subject"
msg["To"] = "test@dispostable.com"
msg["From"] = "********@mail.com"
server="smtp.mail.com"
port=587
pwd="********"

context=ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP(server, port=port) as smtp:
    smtp.starttls(context=context)
    smtp.login(msg["From"], pwd)
    smtp.send_message(msg)
```

And here is the output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 17, in <module>
    smtp.login(msg["From"], pwd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 730, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 721, in login
    initial_response_ok=initial_response_ok)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/smtplib.py", line 642, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'Authentication credentials invalid')
```

I was reluctant to publish my email credentials but trust me they do work when I log in to [www.mail.com](http://www.mail.com). So why they do not work over SMTP?

Comment: Do you need `********@mail.com` to login, or just `********`?

Comment: It should be the first option but tried both

Comment: I have an account and added my credentials. And can confirm that this code works well. In fact, i upvote the question...    from = `your regular email address`, pwd = `your regular password`.

Comment: Hm... could it be that not all mail.com accounts are allowed to authenticate over SMTP then?

Comment: no.   i would say that the credentials are invalid.  since the exact same code works for me....    what is your full email address (if somebody sends you an email) ?   And are you sure that you have your password correct ?

Comment: Absolutely positive. I even copy-pasted everything as opposed to typing to avoid doubts. Tried several times. Besides the code which worked a year before with the same credentials does not work now with the same error.

Comment: Any more ideas?